# Mercurial checkout in Jenkins 2.0 pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, jenkins-plugins, dsl, jenkins-2

We are new to jenkins 2.0. What we are going to do is to define a Jenkinsfile and to do a checkout in stage one. We tried a lot to checkout our project from our mercurial repository but with every try we ran into other issues. 
Questions:
Is it possible to use the mercurial plugin?

what we tried is:

```
checkout([$class: 'MercurialSCM', branches: [[name: '*/default']], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://pathToOurRepo.com']]])
```

but got this exeption:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM.cachedSource(MercurialSCM.java:915)
at hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM.clone(MercurialSCM.java:766)
at hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM.checkout(MercurialSCM.java:556)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:213)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there anybody who can help us with this issue?

Comment: How is this related to DSLs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'MercurialSCM', source: 'ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/repo', clean: true, credentialsId: '1234-5678-abcd'], poll: false
```

[More information](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-scm-step-plugin/blob/master/README.md#generic-scm-step)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone interested in pulling only specific branches, or say the `tip` of a Mercurial repository, this worked for me:

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'MercurialSCM',
    source: 'ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/username/repo-name',
    revision: 'tip',
    clean: true,
    credentialsId: '{your-jenkins-bitbucket-creds}'],
poll: false
```